# Understanding JSON structure - attributes and values

Tags: javascript, json

Something is bothering me. I've used JSON in a few of my apps/websites, we all love it! However something entered my head today which I've never thought about.. take a look at the following example (this is taken from http://json.org/example.html ):

```
{"widget": {
    "debug": "on",
    "window": {
        "title": "Sample Konfabulator Widget",
        "name": "main_window",
        "width": 500,
        "height": 500
    },
    "image": { 
        "src": "Images/Sun.png",
        "name": "sun1",
        "hOffset": 250,
        "vOffset": 250,
        "alignment": "center"
    },
    "text": {
        "data": "Click Here",
        "size": 36,
        "style": "bold",
        "name": "text1",
        "hOffset": 250,
        "vOffset": 100,
        "alignment": "center",
        "onMouseUp": "sun1.opacity = (sun1.opacity / 100) * 90;"
    }
}}
```

now if this was expressed as XML: we would have the following:

```
<widget>
    <debug>on</debug>
    <window title="Sample Konfabulator Widget">
        <name>main_window</name>
        <width>500</width>
        <height>500</height>
    </window>
    <image src="Images/Sun.png" name="sun1">
        <hOffset>250</hOffset>
        <vOffset>250</vOffset>
        <alignment>center</alignment>
    </image>
    <text data="Click Here" size="36" style="bold">
        <name>text1</name>
        <hOffset>250</hOffset>
        <vOffset>100</vOffset>
        <alignment>center</alignment>
        <onMouseUp>
            sun1.opacity = (sun1.opacity / 100) * 90;
        </onMouseUp>
    </text>
</widget>
```

When looking at JSON to XML transformation I'm wondering if is there is any way that you can distinguish if a pair ("key":"value") are a attribute of a tag. For example, in our JSON above

```
"window": {
            "title": "Sample Konfabulator Widget",
            "name": "main_window",
```

title is represented as an attribute of the window tag whilst name is a tag in it's own right, however this isn't expressed anywhere (that I can see).

```
<window title="Sample Konfabulator Widget">
    <name>main_window</name>
```

Why isn't this displayed as:

```
<window>
    <title>Sample Konfabulator Widget</title>
    <name>main_window</name>
```

Is their a way I can specify if a pair are an attribute of the parent tag or a child tag in their own right? Sorry if my wording is bad or if I'm not explaining myself well.

Comment: Do you have an XML schema or something? Neither XML nor JSON assign any semantic meaning to your data.

Comment: The most common convention I saw in plenty of xml-to-json transformers is to get the attributes starting with a @ in the json. eg: `{"window": {"@title":...`

Comment: @Mic - That's a nice way to do it. I've never seen it before yet your one sentence explanation makes it obvious how it would work.

Comment: @Mike - Note that in other ways XML has more restrictions than JSON, e.g., an XML tag name can't have spaces (or certain other characters), but a JSON key name can include any Unicode character (with just a few subject to escaping). So even ignoring the attribute versus child tag issue there are other things you may find in JSON that you can't directly represent in XML.

Comment: I found this rather eyeopening http://webreflection.blogspot.com/2011/12/on-json-comments.html

Answer (score 6):

Some people tend to use a regular property named "@attributes", giving it the special meaning of "attributes container", but that name does not have any special meaning for the JSON specifications themselves.

To answer to your question, there is no way to distinguish between pairs "key":"value" and attributes, simply because json does not support attributes.

This kind of question usually comes from people who forget that the M in XML stands for "markup", which is a way of taking plain text and adding markup to create structured text.
I guess that the misunderstanding cames from promoting JSON as [a fat-free alternative to XML](http://www.json.org/xml.html), while actually XML is a markup language, and JSON is a data interchange format. No one is really an alternative to the other.

The mixed content is one of the contexts where XML shows its power.

```
<p>What a <b>mess</b> we're in.</p>
```

Trying to express that as JSON, you'll realize that it wasn't designed for the that job.

On the other hand, XML may be quite useful as data interchanger, but that's not what it was designed for or where it's main strengths are.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your converter.

Json does not match XML 1-1.

Simply put, json is just a way to represent dictionaries and arrays mutally nested.

Answer (score 1):

Some converters are using some default keywords like 'title' and 'src' that are being tranformed as an attribute instead of a field. Some converters do not.

Comment: Glad to read people are still thinking... _I think_ some kind of  reference for your thought would be great, so i could know if a tool does this (= based on what specification)

Answer (score 1):

Not within JSON. I'm assuming you used some kind of automatic way to convert to XML from JSON; depending on the program that's doing the transformation there may be annotations you can use. See also eg. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON which gives two XML examples for the same JSON.

There is no formal specification (that I know of) of how you're "supposed" to map JSON to XML. Both are formalized, structured ways to represent data, but leave the concrete parts of how you represent the data up to you. So it depends how you want to represent the data, and what your application can or cannot deal with.

Answer (score 0):

I just read this exact example on json website and thought "how on earth is title an attribute there's nothing to signify it should. I'd presume the example itself isn't wrong - but I don't know why anyone hasn't offered a simple answer?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is (somewhat) handled in that 'title' and 'description'  (and 'default') are considered keywords in JSON.  JSON doesn't really handle attributes that way.  I think the only way to do it would be to add another encapsulating object just to separate 'title' from the other entries.  I think JSON's effort to make 'title' and 'description' special is an effort to deal with this.  (Not a wonderful answer, I know....)

https://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/reference/generic.html

Answer (score 0):

The object "title" in "widget/window" will be generated into a new element. It will never get in to a attribute of another element. Very sure about this.

Comment: I am not sure if that really *answers* the question. It rather reads like a comment that gives a bit information, but not much more.